# Создать запрос к БД из телеграм бота на Java Spring

Tags: java, telegram-bot, spring

Всем добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Пишу бота, столкнулась с проблемой, что совершенно не понимаю, как составить запрос на чтение из БД.

За основу брала примеры из гугла.

Таблица:

```
@Entity(name = "usersNotes")
public class Notes {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long noteId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long chatId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String note;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Timestamp registredAt;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String userName;
}
```

Репозиторий:

```
public interface NotesRepository extends CrudRepository<Notes, Long> {
    @Query("select * from usersNotes u where u.chatId = :chatId")
    Optional<Notes> findByTitle(@Param("chatId") Long chatId);
}
```

Метод добавления записи:

```
  private void addNotes(Message msg, String text, long chatID) {
        var chat = msg.getChat();
        Notes notes = new Notes();
            notes.setChatId(chatID);
            notes.setNote(text);
            notes.setUserName(chat.getUserName());
            notes.setRegistredAt(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            notesRepository.save(notes);
    }
```

Пыталась оперировать аналогичными запросами добавлению, на чтение - но результат плачевный.
Написать полноценный запрос в репозитории через:

```
@Query("select note from usersNotes where chatId = :chatId LIMIT 1")
    String findMyNote(@Param("chatId") Long chatId);
```

но получаю полотно ошибок даже на этапе запуска проекта:

```
rg.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'botInitializer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bot'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'telegramBot': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notesRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notesRepository' defined in com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at com.example.dio.testBot.TestBotApplication.main(TestBotApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'telegramBot': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notesRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notesRepository' defined in com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notesRepository' defined in com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:107) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1061) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:365) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.dio.testBot.model.NotesRepository.findMyNote(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:51) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:169) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:253) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column 77 [select note from com.example.dio.testBot.model.Notes where chatId = :chatId LIMIT 1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:757) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy89.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column 77 [select note from com.example.dio.testBot.model.Notes where chatId = :chatId LIMIT 1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    ... 77 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Помогите мне, пожалуйста!

Comment: вам помочь прочитать сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Было бы не плохо, понять где я допустила ошибку и как исправить. Если сможете написать пример запроса, буду так же при много благодарна, так как своему стыду не могу разобраться сама

Comment: окей, прочитайте сообщения об ошибках, там много полезного

Comment: Хорошо быть умным и сразу во всем разбираться. Вы наверное никогда не попадали в сложные ситуации и всегда все понимали сами, ни о чем не спрашивали. Это правда, здорово! =)

Comment: вы или учитесь разбираться в том, что вам пишет консолька, или остаётесь ждать принца, который вам всё разжуёт и в рот положит. это ваша работа, за вас её никто делать не будет (на постоянной основе). я вам подсказываю где искать решение, а вы продолжаете ждать конкретного решения от меня, не пытаясь прислушаться. это как в истории про помочь рыбой или удочкой, если понимаете о чём я

Comment: Я пыталась понять в чем допустила ошибку, но не смогла, по этому задала вопрос. Если бы могла не спрашивать, то так и поступила бы. В любом случае Вы хотели помочь и за помощь Вам спасибо

Comment: так вы конкретизируйте что именно вам не понятно, что вы уже делали для решения проблемы. ещё раз, В КОНСОЛИ ВСЁ НАПИСАНО. вам уже советовали в предыдущих ваших вопросах читать сообщения консоли вдумчиво, мотайте на ус. успехов

Comment: Anatol, видимо тяжелая ночь... Ладно, Вы были правы, признаюсь! Спасибо, правда! Но  как тогда лимит задать? Это Вы можете подсказать?)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю зачем вам свой запрос и почему `findByTitle` возвращает одну сущность, у вас соотношение один к одному? Если так, может ваша сущность `Notes ` будет иметь уникальный ключ **chatId** вместо **noteId**?

Так же в Spring вы можете задать в названии метода условия фильтрации, условно: `Collection<Notes> findAllByChatId(Long chatId)`  в данном случае в названии метода вы просите найти все сущности `findAllBy` и указываете поле из вашей сущности `Notes` - то есть `ChatId`. 

Можете прочитать подробнее [здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)